# Turning open source software into a consulting business?

Tags: open-source

Just some general and specific questions about running a business which uses open source software and sells training, services, and other value added solutions utilizing the Open Source asset(s) (software,framework,suite,solution).

1. How much modification do you need to make to an existing open source software/framework to create your own brand? Open Source (GPLv3) branding issues here....copyright and trademark issues as well..... for ex) Mambo and Joomla, I think they are pretty much same? But they have different labels.
   More specifically my concern is, how to avoid trademark/copyright infringement while promoting the open source asset? Is it best to simply relabel the open source asset with my own?
2. Is there a disadvantage of promoting open source software/framework/suite in hopes of selling value added services and solutions on top of the Open Source asset?
3. Can Open Source assets be marketing point for lowered Total Ownership Cost and transparency? Meaning, clients will not be using some mysterious, opaque proprietary asset?
4. Is competition fierce? Cost of developing software is non existing because you are using an open source asset. Barrier to entry is minimal?

Comment: In most cases you won't be selling the open source software (as the license will prohibit it), you will be selling your consulting skills in relation to that product. So there isn't really a copyright issue, as long as you follow the applicable license.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about startups.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question would be more relevant to be posted on [answers.onstartups.com](http://answers.onstartups.com/) and you would most likely get better responses as most of the members are entrepreneurs.

There has been [a discussion](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/9877/making-money-out-of-a-free-and-open-source-application) there about this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to create your own brand; you want to profit from the existing brand's popularitly. Focus on a single system or a related range of systems and promote yourself in that area:

- start a blog
- visist conferences
- participate on sites (i.e. StackOverflow)
- contribute to the project itself. Code, documentation, design.

In general, be a good Open Source citizen. You will need your open source network for your references.